# Getting old values from Jtable

Tags: java, jtable

I am facing a strange problem with the Jtable. I have a small standalone java application in which I have used Jtable that shows data that is retrieved from database. User can view and edit the data. Once he edit the cell and presses the update button then the edited values will be updated in the database. Now what happening is for the first time when user edit the data and click on update button then the values are properly persisted in the database and user gets out of the module. But again if he/she goes to the same module and edits some more cells and click on update button then in back end i get old value from those cells although the Jtable shows the latest updated values in the cells.

Below is the code.

```
    private JTable jt;
    private TableRowSorter<TableModel> tableSorter; 
    private Dao dao=new Dao();

updateDetails.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                boolean isSuccessful = true;
                int rowCount = jt.getRowCount();
                List<EmployeeMaster> empMasterList = new ArrayList<>();
                int j = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                    EmployeeMaster master = new EmployeeMaster();
                    j = 0;
                        try {
                                master.setEmpId(Long.parseLong((String) jt.getValueAt(i, j)));
                                j++;
                                compId.setName(Long.parseLong((String) jt.getValueAt(i, j)));
                                j++;
                                compId.setNumber((String) jt.getValueAt(i, j));
                                j++;
                                empMasterList.add(master);
                            }
                            dao.updateAllEmpDetails(empMasterList);
                            homePanel.setVisible(true);
                         UpdateEmp.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            });

getDataFromDBtoJtable.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            List<EmployeeMaster> empMasterList = dao.getAllEmpDetails();
            String data[][] = new String[empMasterList.size()][3];
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            for (EmployeeMaster employeeMaster : empMasterList) {
                j = 0;
                data[i][j] = String.valueOf(employeeMaster.getEmpId());
                j++;
                data[i][j] = String.valueOf(employeeMaster.getName());
                j++;
                data[i][j] = String.valueOf(employeeMaster.getNumber());
                i++;
            }
            String column[] = { "ID", "Name", "Number"};
            jt = new JTable(data, column) {

                public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                    if (column == 0 || column == 1 || column == 2)
                        return false;
                    else
                        return true;
                };
            };
            tableSorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(jt.getModel());
            jt.setBounds(12, 12, 1200, 400);
            jt.setRowSorter(tableSorter);
            homePanel.setVisible(false);
            UpdateEmp.setVisible(true);
            JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(jt);
            pane.setBounds(1, 40, 1150, 300);
            setBounds(0, 0, 2000, 800);
            UpdateEmp.add(pane);

        }
    });
```

updateDetails -> button to get the data from jtable and update it in database

getDataFromDBtoJtable -> button to get data from Database and show it in Jtable

Whenever user hits the updateDetails i am updating the database and forcing user to get out of the module. So everytime whenever user get into jtable module he/she gets new Jtable instance. But still unable to identify what's going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you know how to use a JTable? JTable is based on the MVC pattern. You need to update the table model, not the JTable itself. The JTable is only there to display whatever is in the TableModel, so naturally, if you update the JTable directly and refresh it, it's getting data from the underlying table model, which is why you're seeing "old" data. Probably time to look at a tutorial.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Issue is that I am able to view the latest changes in jtable but when i actually get the values from jtable it gives old values.

Comment: Again, *how* do you "get the values from jtable?"

Comment: using jtable getValueAT(row, column). @MarsAtomic

Comment: Again, are you sure you understand how to use a JTable? I will repeat this one more time: you need to get values from the TableModel, not the table, and you need to change values in the TableModel, not the table. [Start your mugging!](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)!